# unable to start glass fish server in eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish-4

When I try to start glass fish server on my eclipse kepler it is showing error message, but when I start from asadmin batch file it is starting normally.

Now it is showing from asadmin start-domain executed successfully, but when I try to access the admin page localhost:4848 it is showing webpage is not available.

Error message printed on console:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform

ERROR: Error creating bundle cache. (java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Access is denied))
java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Access is denied)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:168)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:640)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:90)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:645)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Access is denied)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:168)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:640)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
    at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.newFramework(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:135)
    ... 9 more
Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(GlassFishMain.java:203)
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
ERROR: Error creating bundle cache. (java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Access is denied))
java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Access is denied)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:168)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:640)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:90)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:645)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Access is denied)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:168)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:640)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
    at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.newFramework(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:135)
    ... 9 more
Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(GlassFishMain.java:203)
```